# nadavfima google cards library data not displaying

Tags: java, android, api, android-layout

I am making an application which displays weather information. To display the weather, i am using the nadavfima google cards ui library. But, when i try to set the textviews in my layout for the card, it does not display even after refreshing in the app. All it displays is the hardcoded values i set in the xml file.

```
mCards = (CardUI) root.findViewById(R.id.nowCards);
    mCards.setSwipeable(false);

    // add cards

    // add overview card
    mCards.addCard(new NowOverviewCard());
    mCards.addStack(new CardStack());

    // add temperature
    mCards.addCard(new SimpleTempCard(getActivity()));
    mCards.addStack(new CardStack());

    // add detailed values
    SimpleValueCard pressure = new SimpleValueCard(getActivity());
    mCards.addCard(pressure);
    mCards.refresh();
```

layout view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="15dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/simpleCardHead"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:text="Humidity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/simpleCardValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/simpleCardHead"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/simpleCardHead"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/simpleCardHead"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:text="75%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Card view

```
public class SimpleValueCard extends Card {

View card;
private Context ctx;

public SimpleValueCard( Context ctx) {
this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public View getCardContent(Context context) {
    return getViewFromContext(context);
}

@Override
public boolean convert(View convertCardView) {

    getViewFromContext(ctx);

    TextView header = (TextView) convertCardView
            .findViewById(R.id.simpleCardHead);
    TextView value = (TextView) convertCardView
            .findViewById(R.id.simpleCardValue);

    if (header == null || value == null) {

    } else {
        header.setText("Pressure");
        value.setText("84");
    }
    return true;
}

private View getViewFromContext(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    card = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_simple_value, null);

    return card;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling getViewFromContext(ctx); which return view object but unfortunately you are not using/saving that view object in your convert(View convertCardView).

So you need to store that returned view object & then you should use it in your convert(View convertCardView). It is just like custom listview baseadapter. You need that view object with the help of it you can set your textviews. Because here you are inflating but not exactly using that view object thatswhy its showing static values.

Do above thing, it will surely solve your problem.

Refer Android Custom ListView + BaseAdapter

Comment: Hello RIT, I tried doing that, and set convertCardView to the getViewFromContext(ctx) method, but it still isn't giving me the data, it just shows the hard coded values.

Comment: Instead of writing getViewFromContext(), just copy/paste the code which is inside getViewFromContext() in your convert() method.Your problem will be solved.